How to define a channel-wise finite-differencing kernel in tensorflow
I want to implement spatial finite differences using a tensorflow conv2d layer with a fixed kernel.
My input data X is of size (nbatch,nx,ny,nchannel) and the output Y must be of the same shape with
Y[batch, i, j, channel] == 
  0.5 * (X[batch, i, j+1, channel] - 
         X[batch, i, j-1, channel])

The corresponding Conv2D 3-by-3 kernel would be something like
[[0, -0.5, 0], 
 [0,    0, 0], 
 [0,  0.5, 0]] 

I don't understand how this must be expanded along the input and output channel dimensions so that the same kernel is applied to each input channel individually as required.

I think I figured it out:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import initializers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Layer, Conv2D

# define custom finite spatial 2d conv layer applied to each channel
# invidually, input shape: (batch, channels, nx, ny) output shape: the same
class FixedSpatialKernelLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, kernel, **kwargs):
        super(FixedSpatialKernelLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kernel = tf.constant(kernel, dtype=tf.float32)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        n_channels = input_shape[-1]
        self.conv2d = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=n_channels,
            kernel_size=(3, 3),
            padding='same',
            use_bias=False,
            trainable=False,
            kernel_initializer=initializers.Constant(value=0.0)
        )
        self.conv2d.build(input_shape) 
        kernel_weights = self.conv2d.weights[0].numpy()
        for i in range(n_channels):
          kernel_weights[:,:,i,i] = self.kernel
        self.conv2d.set_weights([kernel_weights])
        super(FixedSpatialKernelLayer, self).build(input_shape)
    def call(self, x):
        return self.conv2d(x)

The trick is to initialise the kernel weights to zero, and then set kernel_weight[:,:,i,i] to the desired 3 by 3 kernel.
Some testing:
# centered finite differencing kernels
kernel_x = np.array([[0,    0,   0],
                     [-0.5, 0, 0.5],
                     [0,    0,   0]], dtype=np.float32)
kernel_y = np.array([[0, -0.5, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0.5, 0]], dtype=np.float32)

# Create layer instances for zonal and latitudinal differencing
dX_dx_layer = FixedSpatialKernelLayer(kernel_x)
dX_dy_layer = FixedSpatialKernelLayer(kernel_y)

# test the layers
X = tf.random.normal((1, 3, 3, 2)) 
dX_dx = dX_dx_layer(X)
dX_dy = dX_dy_layer(X)
assert(dX_dx[0,1,1,0] == 0.5 * X[0,1,2,0] - 0.5*X[0,1,0,0])
assert(dX_dx[0,1,1,1] == 0.5 * X[0,1,2,1] - 0.5*X[0,1,0,1])
assert(dX_dy[0,1,1,0] == 0.5 * X[0,2,1,0] - 0.5*X[0,0,1,0])
assert(dX_dy[0,1,1,1] == 0.5 * X[0,2,1,1] - 0.5*X[0,0,1,1])

